# C# Implicit/Explicit Type Conversion

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

I have a simple scenario that may or may not be possible.  I have a class that contains an integer, for this purpose I'll make it as simple as possible:

```
public class Number
{
    public int Value {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

public static void Print(int print)
{
    Console.WriteLine(print);
}

public static string Test()
{
    Number num = new Number (9, "Nine");
    Print(num); //num "overloads" by passing its integer Value to Print.
}

// Result
// 9
```

How do I make the `Test()` function work as I have coded it?  Is this even possible?  I *think* this can be done with the explicit/implicit operator but I can't figure it out.

Comment: You can use the `implicit` operator, but why is it so important that your class can be implicitly cast to an integer? Just passing `num.Value` seems like a much, much better solution.

Comment: I got it figured out.  I had the syntax completely wrong.  I'm doing this because the class implies a value; I think its clear just to add the implicit part that returns .Value anyway.

Comment: Related question of mine that you may find interesting: [Are implicity/explicit conversion methods inherited in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/967630/119527)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try something like this

```
    public static implicit operator int(Number num)
    {
        return num.Value;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class Number
{  
    public static implicit operator int(Number n)
    {
       return n.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why post an answer of your own when one was already provided? You should just vote up that one, instead.

Comment: Because I answered it when there were no other answers.  I was a minute away.

Answer (score 1):

**Implicit conversion**

```
// Implicit conversion. num long can
// hold any value an int can hold, and more!
int num = 2147483647;
long bigNum = num;
```

**Explicit Conversion**

```
class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        double x = 1234.7;
        int a;
        // Cast double to int.
        a = (int)x;
        System.Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
}
```

Hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

**Implicit type conversion:** Implicit type conversion takes place between smaller to larger integral types but not vice-versa or between derived class and base class. Conversion takes place in type safe manner by C# and no data loss takes place.
For example,

```
int a = 10;
long b = a;
float f = a;
```

**Explicit type conversion:** Explicit type conversion done by using built-in C# functions. Data may be lost while explicit type conversion, means if we convert double to int then precision may be lost. Explicit type conversion require casting. To do a casting, need to specify the type that you are casting to in front of the value or variable to be converted.

For example,

```
double d = 10.20;
int a = (int)d;
//Output: 10
```

To understand in details follow [C# Basics - C# Type Conversion](https://tutorialsbytes.blogspot.com/2019/09/c-basics-c-type-conversion.html)

Comment: "no data loss takes place" is not really accurate, a `float` (.NET `Single`) cannot accurately represent all values possible in an `int`.