# Is it possible to box an integer to a custom type object?

Tags: c#, casting, boxing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Implicit/Explicit Type Conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062213/c-sharp-implicit-explicit-type-conversion)

I have an int that I am attempting to box, so as to use it in a constructor which takes as a parameter object of `CustomType`.

An example of what I mean.

```
 int x = 5;
 object a = x;

 CustomType test = new CustomType(a)

 //constructor in question
 public CustomType(CustomType a)
 {
   //set some variables etc
 }
```

Howver I get the following error

```
 The best overloaded method match for X has some invalid arguments.
```

So obviously I'm way off the mark.  Where am I going wrong? Is boxing the right solution or should i be looking at type casting?

Comment: What are you going to be using this `CustomType` for?

Comment: Your error doesn't seem to match the code you provided. Either that or your provided example is way off the mark. Can you give a more complete example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: K; take a step back... What are you trying to do? If you want to pass an integer to a constructor, an integer parameter would be fine..,

Comment: Make sure that CustomType inherits from Object, if you want to use it that way.

Comment: *Most* everything inherits from `Object`, so I'm still not sure what you're getting at

Comment: I know that using an integer parameter in the constructor would have made more sense, im just playing around with the idea at the moment to see if its even possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That constructor takes a `CustomType` type as a parameter; you're passing it an `int`.  An `int` is not a `CustomType`, and the C# language knows of no implicit conversions from `int` to `CustomType`.  That's why you're getting an error.

Casting the `int` to an `object` doesn't change the fact that it's still not a `CustomType`.

Looking at that particular constructor, it's a copy constructor.  It takes a type of itself as a parameter.  There is (one would hope) another constructor that takes another parameter, whether that's an int, or some other type that you haven't mentioned, or possibly no parameters and you need to just set a property after creating a default object.

As for actual solutions, there are many.  Here are a few:

1. Add an additional constructor to `CustomType` that accepts an `int`.
2. Define a function that takes an `int` as a parameter and returns a `CustomObject`; this would be a "conversion" function that you could use.
3. Use a default constructor of `CustomType` and set a property with your integer (may or may not be applicable, depending on what `CustomType` does.

Boxing doesn't seem to be related to the issue at hand.  It's not something that you *should* use to pass an integer to a custom type.  If you would like to know more about what boxing is, how it works, or when it's useful then consider asking a question that addresses those points because this particular problem would be *harmed* by using boxing as a solution, not helped.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think boxing or casting is what you're looking for. If you want to pass an integer into your constructor, your constructor should be defined like this:

```
public CustomType(int a) {
}
```

Or if you want it to be an object.

```
public CustomType(object a) {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor looks like a Copy-constructor (to copy an object).

if you want to pass an object variable to your CustomType constructor, then the syntax has to be:

```
public CustomType(Object a)
 {
   //Unboxing
   int value = (int) a;
 }
```

Comment: if you're just going to cast it to an int, why not accept an `int` parameter in the first place?

Comment: As a student we see the principles of boxing and unboxing in class.
Sometimes we get exercises to box and unbox values to understand these principles. So I am guessing his question is rather a question to understand the theory rather then to program in this way.

Comment: And yet this code in no way demonstrates any principals about boxing, nor does boxing appear to be actually relevant in the question, merely what the OP thought was relevant but isn't.  In any case, you should at least indicate that this is an obtuse code sample to demonstrate...something (along with explaining what it demonstrates) rather than proposing it as if it's a solution someone would actually use in a real application.

Comment: Servy, Valentijn is correct im trying to understand boxing and type casting and playing around with some examples.

Comment: @cosmicsafari Okay, then what are you trying to do?  What are you trying to demonstrate?  What do you currently know about the subject, and what aspects of boxing are confusing you?  Rather than writing obscure code that's not useful or not even "correct" in what it does to demonstrate a principle, you'll end up learning more about it, and how you should actually use it, when you use that principle to solve an actual solution in a way that really is appropriate to use in the real world.  If you don't, you may learn *how* to do *X* but you won't learn *when* to use *X*.

Comment: @cosmicsafari This page might help you understand the concept a little more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx

Comment: The `mixedList` shown in this msdn page is indeed a good example for boxing and unboxing.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Explicit Type Conversion and implement some operators for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use Generics.

```
public CustomType<T>(T a)
{
//set some variables etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can box `int` to `object` but not to an arbitrary type and you cannot take something out of the box that is not in the box. I.e. `int i = (int)(object)5;` will work, but `CustomType x = (CustomType)(object)5;` will not work.

You would need a constructor accepting an `int`

```
public CustomType(int a) {
    ....
}
```

---

By the way, you created strange recursion. If the only constructor requires a `CustomType` then you need another `CustomType` object for the initialization of the first one

```
 CustomType ct = new CustomType(new CustomType(new CustomType(null)));
```

Comment: You assume that's the only constructor.  Odds are either it takes something else entirely or it's just one of several constructors.  It's also possible to have a class that derived from `CustomType` and provides another constructor that could be passed to the `CustomType` to create it, but that would just be...awkward (and then there is `null`, as you showed).

Answer (score 0):

Boxing is what happens when you convert a (value of a) value type to either

1. a direct or indirect base class (in the case of `int` that could be the `ValueType` class or the `object` class
2. an interface that the value type implements (in the case of `int` that could be either `IComparable`, `IFormattable`, `IConvertible`, `IComparable<int>`, or `IEquatable<int>`)

Since you can never make `int` have other base classes or implement more interfaces, it's not possible to box an `int` into `CustomType`.

If you write your own `struct` then *you* decide what interfaces it implements, and in that case values of your `struct` can be boxed into each of those interface types. (You can't change the base classes of a `struct`, though.)

Inside your class/struct `CustomType` it **is** possible to define an [implicit conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) from `int` to `CustomType`. In this way, it will be legal to say

```
CustomType ct = 5;
```

But it's not boxing. It's just an "invisible" call to your `implicit operator` method. The original object `5` is not put into a box; it is just the argument to your operator method.